# PHP move_uploaded_file not working when inside a function?

Tags: php

When trying to create a function that handles uploading a file to the server, I am getting strange results when I try to put the exact same code block into a function call.  Not too sure why. The directory permissions are good and I have run side by side tests on this and cannot get it to work. The upload.php is being called via an AJAX POST.  Could this be why? More specifically I am using the plugin from here: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php

This works:

```
<?php
$fn = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
$fs = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
$ft = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
$tn = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$directory = "uploads/";
$tp = $directory . $fn;
move_uploaded_file($tn,$tp);
?>
```

This does not work:

```
<?php
function moveFile(){
    $fn = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    $fs = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];
    $ft = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
    $tn = $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $directory = "uploads/";
    $tp = $directory . $fn;
    move_uploaded_file($tn,$tp);
}
moveFile();
?>
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would fail in a function.

Comment: you tagged as jquery and ajax; relevance?

Comment: Me neither, I am not doing anything out of the ordinary. But I get a 500 internal server error when using the plugin and doing this in the upload.php file?

Comment: Did you check the webserver's and php's errorlog?

Comment: check your logs then or `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. what I can tell, is probably a scope issue. But again; relevance to jquery/ajax?

Comment: @Fred-ii- None, as it is a serverside issue, I've removed the tags. He thought they're necessary because he uses AJAX and jQuery.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois OP states: *"The upload.php is being called via an AJAX POST."* - and you removed the tags. What OP should have done was post relevant code.

Comment: Add `global $_FILES;` at the top of your function(within the function, first line).

Comment: @AndrewCoder IIRC `$_FILES` is a superglobal variable.

Comment: Ahh, of this I was unaware :)  Thanks.

Comment: Even trying this: moveFile($_FILES["myfile"]["name"], $_FILES["myfile"]["size"], $_FILES["myfile"]["type"], $_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]); does not work? I also tried it with the directory on the outside of the scope and no luck?  Completely stumped on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function moveFile($file){
    $fn = $file["name"];
    $fs = $file["myfile"]["size"];
    $ft = $file["myfile"]["type"];
    $tn = $file["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $directory = "uploads/";
    $tp = $directory . $fn;
    move_uploaded_file($tn,$tp);
}
moveFile($_FILES['myfile']);
```